# Vue :state, what is this?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vuelidate

i was using https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/validation#vuelidate and i came across with

`:state` as a vue attribute.

i didn't found anything in the docs and i am confused. where is it come from and what does it do?
actually seems like i need to use this to validate a input field. but i'd rather would like to use @blur instead of state but its not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#comp-ref-b-form-select-props):

> **state** - Boolean   - null
>
> Controls the validation state appearance of the component. 'true' for valid, 'false' for invalid', or 'null' for no validation state

and to bind this property dynamically we can use `v-bind` directive like:

```
<b-form-select
   id="example-input-2"
   v-bind:state="validateState('food')"
></b-form-select>
```

or we can use the shorthand for `v-bind:state` which is just `:state` like:

```
<b-form-select
   id="example-input-2"
   :state="validateState('food')"
></b-form-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

the "state" is not an attribute but a property, one of the properties in the child component which is expecting a boolean value which you are passing from you main vue file or referred to as "parent component"

The attribute being used here is "v-bind" or ":" in shorthand, then passing the property "state" hence ":state"